# Download and modify file from Git Repository using Ruby Grit over SSH

Tags: ruby, git, ssh, github, grit

How can I download a file (or clone the repo) from a secure Git Repo (e.g. SSH on GitHub), then commit changes back to the repo using Ruby Grit?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Grit gives you object oriented read/write access to Git repositories via Ruby.
>   -- http://grit.rubyforge.org/

Grit is just for interacting with a local repo, it doesn't manage remote ops (clone/push/pull/fetch) for you.

Comment: I see. Would you suggest I use ruby-git? The reason I leaned towards grit was because the author said ruby-git is no longer being maintained, and he is working on grit: https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git/wiki.

Comment: I'd suggest straight up git.  You still have to have git for grit anyway.